# Angularjs and Web Api - JSON formatting issue

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a lightweight Angularjs app and I'm trying to process json from my ASP.NET Web Api controller.

In the angularjs factory:

```
adapter.getLegacyCouriers = function(id) {
  return $http({
    method: 'GET', 
    url: 'http://legacywebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/legacycourier'
  });
}
```

In the controller:

```
legacyService.getLegacyCouriers()
.success(function (response) {
       alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(response));
})
.error(function (response) { 
    alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(response)); 
});
```

When I exchange the URL in the $http get [with this one](http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo) it hits the **success** block. However, my default URL which returns json formatted in the same way hits the **error** block.

Can someone help me? Both returns application/json response headers, and both return a status of 200 OK (using Chrome to debug). I can't figure out why my json is hitting the error block.

Comment: @mmeverdies this message correspond as the example of success request

Comment: @rnrneverdies I wasn't getting that "daily limit" message when I was testing the geonames api. It was returning an actual json result set that was formatted the exact (or so I believe) same way as my one returned from the Web Api controller.

Comment: Looks like a paremeter issue. Probly the method has no default parameters. Something is happening in the server side. Try to log any exception in the api

Comment: @Fals There is no server side error as you can see by testing the URL: http://legacywebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/legacycourier - it responds with a 200 OK and the application/json header

Comment: Strange! Try to replace for $http.get(...) then.

Comment: I've got response No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://run.jsbin.com' is therefore not allowed access.  from your http://legacywebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/legacycourier  please see here http://jsbin.com/nugif/1/edit

Comment: @sss Thank you so much!! I had to enable cross-origin resource sharing. I don't know why I wasn't receiving that header when I was debugging locally with Chrome. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service responing with

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'run.jsbin.com'; is therefore not allowed access.
>   from your legacywebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/legacycourier

please see here [jsbin.com/nugif/1/edit](http://jsbin.com/nugif/1/edit).

Just enable cross-origin resource sharing.